# ldd finds shared library, but executing binary tells "not found"

Tags: ubuntu

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 and installing keepalived's deb, `keeplived` cannot start:

```
aaroot@aatest1:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/keepalived
/usr/sbin/keepalived: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpmibs.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But using `ldd` to check shared library, the missing library (the symbolic link `libnetsnmpmibs.so.30` and the real library) can be found:

```
aaroot@aatest1:~$ sudo ldd /usr/sbin/keepalived|grep libnetsnmpmibs
    libnetsnmpmibs.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpmibs.so.30 (0x00007fd32c3c5000)
```

Re-executing `ldconfig` shows the `libnetsnmpmibs.so.30` is found:

```
aaroot@aaaatest1:~$ sudo ldconfig -v |grep libnetsnmpmibs
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libnetsnmpmibs.so.30 -> libnetsnmpmibs.so.30.0.2
```

Are there any problems?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. After using strace to check system call, I found that binary tried to open ld.so.cache and got permission denied. Though apparmor blocked that behavior and remove apparmor file, and the binary can run perfectly