# Program file exists in /usr/bin, but cannot be used

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, file-permissions

Clearly my file exists in `/usr/bin`

```
$ ls /usr/bin/ngrok
/usr/bin/ngrok
```

However, when I attempt to `chown` it I receive an error

```
$ sudo chown my_user:users /usr/bin/ngrok
chown: cannot dereference '/usr/bin/ngrok': No such file or directory
```

Further attempts to run it also fail!

```
$ ngrok
bash: ngrok: command not found
$ sudo /usr/bin/ngrok
sudo: /usr/bin/ngrok: command not found
```

What is happening here?

Comment: The third point could happen as well if '/usr/bin/' is not in your PATH. You should have tested with `/usr/bin/ngrok` to be a complete symmetry of the following case with `sudo`.

Answer (score 52):

`/usr/bin/ngrok` will be a symlink that points nowhere (or rather to a non-existing file). Check with `ls -l`.

Comment: The "cannot dereference" error is the dead giveaway here.  You don't "dereference" a normal file, you open it.

Comment: Or `readlink -f  /usr/bin/ngrok` to find where the link should point to.

Comment: or `namei -l /usr/bin/ngrok`

Answer (score 5):

Given the `chown` error, the most likely possibility is that it's a symlink, as [answered by Sven](https://serverfault.com/a/895648/229499). However, just for reference in case somebody ends up here for cases where the file exists and is not a link, but gives a command-not-found/file-not-found error, one more possibility is that the executable is dynamically linked and for some reason it's not able to load libraries:

- missing library (run `ldd` on the binary to see those)
- [missing loader](https://askubuntu.com/a/133460/158442)
- [apparmor](https://serverfault.com/a/624867/229499) denying access to a library or loader
- ...

Also, for a script, if the interpreter in the shebang could not be executed for similar reasons, you'd get the same error.

Comment: Even more confusing, this can indeed result in an enigmatic "no such file or directory.".

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option of changing ownership of the symlink itself with

`chown -h my_user:users /usr/bin/ngrok`

if you don't wish (or have permission) to change ownership of the target file.

Comment: I'm not certain how this answers the question - the question is "What is happening here?" and the problem is that the target file doesn't exist. This doesn't solve the problem and it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I suppose you can also interpret the question as "the file does exist (the symlink is a file), why does it tell me otherwise and why can't I change its ownership?" This answer covers that interpretation. Sven's just assumes (probably correctly) the OP wants to work with the target file.

Comment: This is not applicable on a Linux system, which does not have permissions for symlinks.

Comment: @muru *This is not applicable on a Linux system, which does not have permissions for symlinks.*  Actually, Linux is one of the few (is the only?) of POSIX-family OSes that *does* have the ability to set symlink owner/group.  See the Linux [`chown(1)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html).  Possible reasons Linux does this  are discussed at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33180/why-change-the-owner-of-a-symbolic-link-in-linux/33181

Comment: @AndrewHenle and how does that help? Changing owner/group for a symlink makes no difference here since the permissions applied when executing are always of the target file. So you could have a link owned by whoever, but changing the ownership on that link makes absolutely no difference to the permissions considered when executing it.

Comment: @muru *and how does that help?* Read [the question I already linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33180/why-change-the-owner-of-a-symbolic-link-in-linux/33181) since it specifically asks:  "In linux it's possible to change the owner or the group owner of a symbolic link (symlink). **I was wondering why someone would want to do that, since permissions of a symlink are not used when accessing a file through it**"

Comment: @AndrewHenle OK, let me rephrase: how does that help *here*?

Comment: @muru Your statement "This is not applicable on a Linux system" is wrong.

Comment: @AndrewHenle He already admitted that. But applying that to a Linux system does not help anyway.

Comment: @glglgl Read the question that I linked for some answers as to how permissions and ownership of a symlink might be useful (not very, IMO, but someone else might think differently)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Again, this is quite interesting, but not useful for the OP which wonders why their ngrok doesn't exist although it seems to exist. That is what was meant with _here_.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that is only part of my statement. The rest didn't vanish into thin air.